# Make 3D effect in UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, effects

I want to make a 3D look to UIImageView in sqaure to look like a button(round borders and not corners).
I am desesperate and thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the view's CALayer property:

(v can be your UIImageView)

```
[v.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];
[v.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[v.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
[v.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[v.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[v.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
[v.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 5.0)];
```

You can change all of these properties to match your needs or color scheme.

Also, take a look at the [CALayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you Evan but it works but I need light effect I need the left an the top line of the rectangle in gary and the right and bottom line in black for example. It's possible? and thank you again

Comment: If you mean a multi-colored border, this is not possible. Only a single color is currently allowed in Quartz.